# Как конвертируются time-zone?

Tags: php

```
DTSTAMP:20201120T062413Z

(DTSTAMP это временная метка создания сообщения VEVENT в файле ical или ics. Существуют разные типы таких VEVENT-сообщений, создание нового event-объекта является лишь одним из них)
    
LAST-MODIFIED:20201120T062440Z

(LAST-MODIFIED - ПОСЛЕДНЕЕ ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ)

DTEND;TZID="Ekaterinburg Standard Time":20201121T093000
    
Вопрос такой, как сгенерировать c помощью php вторую часть у:
DTSTAMP -"T062413Z";
LAST-MODIFIED - "T062440Z";
DTEND - "T093000";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dt = new \DateTime();

var_dump($dt->format('Ymd\THis\Z'));
```